# Custom view 'CustomAutoCompleteTextView' has setOnTouchListener called on but does not override performClick

Tags: android

I have created a onTouchListener for my AutocompleteTextView. But onTouch() method shows warning:

> If a View that overrides onTouchEvent or uses an OnTouchListener does not also implement performClick and call it when clicks are detected, the View may not handle accessibility actions properly. Logic handling the click actions should ideally be placed in View#performClick as some accessibility services invoke performClick when a click action should occur.

I did not understand what does it means. Here is the code.

```
actvEntryCategory.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                try{
                    actvEntryCategory.clearFocus();
                    actvEntryCategory.requestFocus();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d("eEMP/EntryCreate", "Error raised at EntryCategory touch event due to " + e.toString());
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I am new to Andoird. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> AutocompleteTextView. But onTouch() method shows warning: If a View that overrides onTouchEvent or uses an OnTouchListener does not also implement performClick

FROM DOCS

[**`Handling custom touch events`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/custom-views.html#custom-touch-events)

Custom view controls may require non-standard touch event behavior. For example, a custom control may use the `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` listener method to detect the `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` events and trigger a special click event. In order to maintain compatibility with accessibility services, the code that handles this custom click event must do the following:

1. Generate an appropriate AccessibilityEvent for the interpreted click action.
2. Enable accessibility services to perform the custom click action for users who are not able to use a touch screen.

To handle these requirements in an efficient way, your code should override the `performClick()` method, which must call the super implementation of this method and then execute whatever actions are required by the click event. When the custom click action is detected, that code should then call your `performClick()` method. The following code example demonstrates this pattern.

> **SOLUTIONS**

1. Use **`@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")`** to ignore this warning
2. Second solution Your  custom view should override the [**`performClick()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick()) method,

> SAMPLE code to override the **`performClick()`** method from docs

```
class CustomTouchView extends View {

    public CustomTouchView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    boolean mDownTouch = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);

        // Listening for the down and up touch events
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mDownTouch = true;
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (mDownTouch) {
                    mDownTouch = false;
                    performClick(); // Call this method to handle the response, and
                                    // thereby enable accessibility services to
                                    // perform this action for a user who cannot
                                    // click the touchscreen.
                    return true;
                }
        }
        return false; // Return false for other touch events
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        // Calls the super implementation, which generates an AccessibilityEvent
        // and calls the onClick() listener on the view, if any
        super.performClick();

        // Handle the action for the custom click here

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: but how to set onTouchListener for the AutocompleteTextview like this actvEntryCategory.setOnTouchListener @Nilesh Rathod

Comment: @vishnu didn't get u

Comment: In my code I called setOnTouchListener for actvEntryCategory. when I click on actvEntryCategory, this method will be called. But in your solution, there is no setOnTouchListener. when onTouchEvent is called. can you please make your solution for my code

Comment: @vishnu why you need `TouchListener ` in AutocompleteTextview

Comment: when I click on that AutoCompleteTextview, TouchListener will be called and my customTextview get focused@Nilesh Rathod

Comment: @vishnu which **`customTextview`** share with question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169054/discussion-between-vishnu-and-nilesh-rathod).

Comment: All we want is a valid solution that do not create another file just to make a simple touch listener